# Validators postback unwanted

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple validators in my web page (compare, required, custom). When I click submit button, the page postsback. However I have given same validation group to all the fields. What is wrong?

```
 <div class="innerUserName" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                                    MaxLength="20" Style="margin-left: 28px;" Width="230" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>

                            </div>

 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            <div id="divUserNameAvailability">
                            </div>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqval_UName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName"
                                CssClass="validation" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Provide User Name"
                                SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="SignUp"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <%--User Name Not Available--%>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cusval_UName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                ClientValidationFunction="ValidateUsername" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" CssClass="validation"
                                Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="SignUp"></asp:CustomValidator>


<div class="innerPwd" style="margin-top: 0px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" 
                                    Style="margin-left: 28px;" Width="230" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

 <span>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqval_Pwd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="validation" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Provide Password"
                                ValidationGroup="SignUp" />
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexPassword" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please Provide Valid Password"
                                ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[0-9]+.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]+.*)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,20}$" ValidationGroup="SignUp"
                                CssClass="validation"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator></span>
                        <div>



<asp:Button ID="btnSignUp" runat="server" Text="Create Account" Style="border: 0px;
                                    background-color: #396fd1; font-weight: bold; height: 29px; font-size: 12px;
                                    color: #fff3dd;" ValidationGroup="SignUp" />
```

function:

```
function ValidateUsername(sender, args) {
            var div = document.getElementById("divUserNameAvailability");
            var img = document.getElementById("imgUserNameAvailability");

            if (div.style.display == "none") {
                CallMe("txtUserName");
            }

            if (div.style.display == "inline") {
                var imgFileName = getName(img.src);
                if (imgFileName == "wrong")
                    args.IsValid = false;
                else
                    args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Without looking your code it is very hard to guess.

Comment: If your validators are server-side controls, they will cause a postback.

Comment: I cannot post my code. Its too big that stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post

Comment: Is it the normal behaviour that one of these validator causes the page postback?

Comment: Can you show us the html where you have declared your validators? You don't need to post *all* your code.

Comment: Don't post your code as a comment, instead click the "Edit" button and add the code there (where your original answer is).

Comment: Can you just show us the validators? That's a lot of code

Comment: I have posted some my html along with the validators.

Comment: On customer validator `cusval_UName` you have provided a client side function called `ValidateUsername`, does this function exist in your javascript?

Comment: Post the function. We need to see if it is a valid function and returning what it should.

Comment: Couple thoughts to help troubleshoot... 1) can you confirm that you don't have any JS errors on your page and 2) try isolating just a single simple validator such as RequiredFieldValidator and see if that works.  Slowing introduce them back in until it breaks.